# How to mount Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

```
$ file data
```

Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=9f923f9d-2cbd-4a49-8b5c-6a3cece42509 (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)

```
$ mount -t ext4 data /mnt/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop2,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

Comment: What are the messages in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` when you attempt the mount? And do you know how the file `data` was created? Could it contain an entire disk, with separate partitions?

Comment: I think this is a Docker volume. Still not sure how to access it (outside of Docker) though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot directly access the file (which is not a block device), you need to use a loop block device.

Assuming your kernel has [loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) support,

```
losetup /dev/loop0 /path/to/data

mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

or directly

```
mount -o loop /path/to/data /mnt
```

Comment: From Sato's error `"bad superblock on /dev/loop2"` it sounds like mount might already be automatically using a loop device, but regardless your answer could only help

Comment: You're right. I had not seen the "loop2". Possibly he was then mounting it to an improperly configured loop device.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely see `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` for more details on the error.

In case it was a problem with the filesystem itself, you may need to `fsck` it with `fsck.ext4`, these options should work (verbose, force check, preen or automatically repair). And assuming you've set up a loop device for the file like in lserni's answer with `losetup /dev/loop8 /path/to/data` )

```
fsck.ext4 -vfp /dev/loop8
```

And after it's fixed, try the mount again